# Understading where structure and its items are declared

Tags: c, unix, struct

I have found a simple implementation of Unix's `ls` utility.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *sd;
    dp = opendir(argv[1]);
    while ((sd = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", sd->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

The main question I have is how `d_name` item from the structure is created or where is it located? Is it built-in part of `dirent.h` ?

I know that typically, structure would be created with prototype like this:

```
struct myStructure {
int number;
char name[10];
}
```

And a new variable of that type would be `struct myStructure Variable`.

But in this code I just see `struct dirent *sd` which is pointer to `dirent` structure, if not mistaken, so where is that structure is prototyped ?

Comment: `dirent` is declared in `dirent.h`. For more information you can check it [here.](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4/newsrc/sys/dirent.h.html)

Comment: So it is indeed part of dirent.h ! Thank you.

Comment: `struct dirent` is found in `dirent.h`... Who woulda thought.

Comment: Well it was a guess, but I'd rather ask people who know and learn for sure. I'm just a beginner in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure `dirent` is declared in `dirent.h` as following:

```
struct dirent {
    unsigned long   d_fileno;   /* file number of entry */
    unsigned short  d_reclen;   /* length of this record */
    unsigned char   d_type;     /* file type, see below */
    unsigned char   d_namlen;   /* length of string in d_name */
#ifdef _POSIX_SOURCE
    char    d_name[255 + 1];    /* name must be no longer than this */
#else
#define MAXNAMLEN   255
    char    d_name[MAXNAMLEN + 1];  /* name must be no longer than this */
#endif
};
```

For more information you can visit this link: [Source to sys/dirent.h](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4/newsrc/sys/dirent.h.html)